# Show that $2^r r! \equiv \prod_{k=1}^{r} [(-1)^k k)] \pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let be $\mathbb{P}$ the set of prime numbers, $p \in \mathbb{P} \cap (2\mathbb{Z} + 1)$, $r = \dfrac{p - 1}{2}$.

How do we proceed to show that $2^r r! \equiv \prod_{k=1}^{r} [(-1)^k k] \pmod{p}$.

My attempts started with:

\begin{align*}
r! & = \prod_{k=0}^{r - 1} r - k \\
& = \prod_{k=0}^{r - 1} \dfrac{p - (2k + 1)}{2} \\
& = \dfrac{1}{2^r} \prod_{k=0}^{r - 1} p - (2k + 1)
\end{align*}

Then I have shown that the following mapping is a bijection:

\begin{array}[lcl]
& f & : & [[1, r]] \cap (2\mathbb{Z} + 1) & \longrightarrow & [[r + 1, p - 1]] \cap (2\mathbb{Z}) \\
& &  x & \longmapsto & p - k
\end{array}

I tried to rewrite $r!$ using $f$, but I couldn't do anything with it.

EDIT: Without supplementary laws of Gauss as I am currently trying to show them using this.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$2^r r!\equiv \prod_{k=1}^{r} (-1)^k k \equiv r!(-1)^{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{r} k}\pmod{p}$$

Now, as $r!$ is coprime to $p $, our problem becomes equivalent to $$2^r  \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}} \pmod p$$

Now, as $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) \equiv 2^r \pmod p$ by [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), our next step is to show $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)  \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}} \pmod p$$
Which is shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#The_supplementary_laws_using_Legendre_symbols).

Our proof is done.

Comment: Thank you for this proof, I should have mentioned but it's in order to show the supplementary laws of Gauss, so I cannot rely on them. I'll edit the OP.